# C# SapDataReader cmd.ExecuteReader() Error

Tags: c#, .net, sap-erp, saprfc

I have the following problem. I want to connect my C# application with our SAP server, which works fine, but in addition, I want to a execute an RFC function and read the output with `ExecuteReader()`.

```
using Microsoft.Data.SapClient;


namespace SAPconnect2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connstr = "ASHOST=xxx; SYSNR=00; CLIENT=100; LANG=EN; USER=xxx; PASSWD=xxx;";

            using (SapConnection conn = new SapConnection(connstr))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SapCommand cmd = (SapCommand)conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "exec zrfc_test";
                    using (SapDataReader dr = (SapDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {


                    }
}}}}}
```

But when I execute the program, I get the following error:

> additional information: Incorrect token found, expected a token of the following type: Describe, Execute, Select. [XtractQL/Command]

I also tried to follow this guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185499(v=bts.10).aspx

But when I remove `(SapCommand)` before `conn.CreateCommand()` and `(SapDataReader)` before `cmd.ExecuteReader()`, it generates error:

> CS0266

What do I have to do, to get this program running?

Comment: It seems that CommandType.StoredProcedure is not supported by the SapCommand https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185428(v=bts.10).aspx

Comment: The error message also talks about a token named 'Execute'. Could you try to replace Exec with Execute?

Comment: I get the same error like in my post, except now, the expected token types are: Function, Hierachy, MDx, Report. I really have no clue how to handle this. :/

Comment: As far as I can tell looking at [their own example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/adapters-and-accelerators/adapter-sap/invoke-rfcs-and-bapis-using-the-exec-command-in-sap) your code is correct. Unless there is something wrong inside the function itself. Do you have some other way to test it outside running your own program? I don't know SAP but perhaps there is a way to execute that function from some kind of SAP interface like we do with Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: Yeah, the function itself is correct. I can call it within SAP and get a table as result.